# REST API - Mapping country and state picklist value

Tags: apex, rest-api

We are refreshing accounts in our Salesforce CRM from vendor product using REST API call.

**Country and state picklist values are not matching with Vendor data.**

For eg:
**Salesforce data:**
   Country Picklist value: US
   State Picklist value: Indiana

**Vendor Product data:**

```
Country: United states
State:IN
```

Any better way to convert vendor country and state into our format ?

Comment: What is the vendor product?

Comment: Vendor product Insideview